# Suspiciously low result on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

The following query returns 24 buckets:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "partnerCategory": 6
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "uniqcnpjs": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "partnerId"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result is about 750 buckets long. 24 is very low.

If you take into consideration that if you add up the "doc_count" of each bucket, it doesn't match the number of hits if you don't aggregate.
The sum of the buckets doc_count should be at least 20k. Now it's 2.5k.

So, can anyone tell me what's going on? I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to set the `size` option of the `terms` aggregation to a very high value? e.g.,

```
"aggs": {
  "uniqcnpjs": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "partnerId",
      "size": 1000
    }
  }
}
```

Also, checks whether also the result of the `cardinality` aggregation is lower than what you expect. e.g.,

```
"aggs": {
  "cardinality_partnerid": {
    "cardinality": {
      "field": "partnerId"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the cardinality gave "better" results. I can't tell if correct because the query itself is run against several indexes and then mapped/reduced to remove duplicated items... is there an option to have cardinality return more than just a number?

Comment: Three questions: (1) have you tried to increase the size? (2) where is the map/reduce logic for removing duplicated items? (3) what do you mean by "more than just a number"?

Comment: I actually ran the numbers here, and for and individual index, the result is correct! the logic to remove duplicates is basically a `myFullColection.Select(I=>i.Key).Distinct()`... and by more than just a number, I was hoping it could output similar to my original post, where I get a structure similar to `{Key:partner-id-here, count:1234}`

Comment: No, for that what you need is the `terms` bucket aggregation that you are already using. I don't know, if you think that the `cardinality` aggregation is giving you the possibly right result, then the only things I can think of is that the `size` option of your `term` aggregation is too low.

Comment: you were correct, the size of the aggregation is not the same as the size of hits!